# Почему не сохраняются изменения в картинке?

Tags: изображения, java

Почему в сохранённой newImage.gif нет изменений?
т.е. алгоритм берёт все первые пиксели в вертикали(31), заносит их в массив и заменяет все идентичные цвета в картинке на белый цвет, но в итоге получается не измененная картинка
      public class Logic {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
}

// -1 - белый цвет
// -16777216 - черный цвет
public static void getImage() throws IOException {
    File input = new File("image.gif");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

    int[] w = new int[image.getHeight()];
    for (int i = 1; i < image.getHeight(); i++) {
        w[i] = image.getRGB(i, 1);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < image.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int g = 1; g < image.getWidth(); g++) {
            if (filter(image.getRGB(g, i), w)) {
                image.setRGB(g, i, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    ImageIO.write(image, "GIF", new File("newImage.gif"));
    System.out.println("готово");
}

private static boolean filter(int RGB, int[] patterns) {
    try {
        for (int n : patterns) {
            if (n == RGB) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: гениальный вопрос...

Comment: @Barmaley, плюсуй, если экстрасенс )))

Comment: Замечание немного не по теме, ибо по теме вроде все уже сказали:
Отлавливать такие исключения, как NullPointerException - не есть хорошо. Их надо не отлавливать и обрабатывать, а писать код так, чтобы у них не было шансов на появление. Например, делать в соответствующих местах проверку на null.

Comment: автор вы слишком рано здались, и поленились сами разобратся почему не работает. поиск ошибок в своем/чужом коде это неотемлимая часть работы программиста

Comment: здались, неотемлимая, разобратся  
согласен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, ошибка тут

```
for (int i = 1; i > image.getWidth(); i++) {
    for (int g = 1; g > image.getHeight(); g++) {
        if (!filter(g, w)){
            image.setRGB(i, g, -1);
        }
    }
}
```

У вас сразу же происходит выход из цикла. Должно быть:

```
for (int i = 1; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
    for (int g = 1; g < image.getHeight(); g++) {
        if (!filter(g, w)){
            image.setRGB(i, g, -1);
        }
    }
}
```

и вот сдесь:

```
for (int i = 1; i < image.getHeight(); i++) {
```

Теперь следующий вопрос - почему именно 31? Давайте уж как-то красиво сделаем:

```
int[] w = new int[image.getHeight()];
```

Ну и занавес:

```
if (!filter(g, w)){
```

почему вы сравниваете цвета одной колонки пикселей с **индексом** массива высоты? Почему тогда не с цветом?

Comment: так ведь
    w[i] = image.getRGB(i, 1);

Comment: int g - это счетчик. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 .... до конца картинки. И вот вы сравниваете:
            if (n == RGB) {
                return true;
            }

другими словами,
(индексМассива == одномуИзЦветов)

Comment: упс, пардоньте, чтото у меня феерическая каша в вакууме затянутая тугим узлом в голове.  Изменил топик на исправленный

Comment: о, теперь, кажись, заработало) ничего страшного, с каждым из нас бывает

Comment: я советую на будущее не писать в качестве счетчиков i,g,k,h,j если они не испольщуются только в одной строчке. 
    for (int heightIndex = 1; heightIndex < image.getHeight(); heightIndex ++) {
        for (int widthIndex = 1; widthIndex < image.getWidth(); widthIndex++) {

вот так бы точно не запутались